# TimeZoneDB - How to query for the local_time by providing the latitude and longitude?

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched in here and on Google, but found no answer to the question.

So, I downloaded [TimeZoneDB](http://timezonedb.com/download) and imported the sql file to MySQL. I can query for the day, date, and local_time by using this (sample for Asia/Manila):

```
    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) + tz.gmt_offset, '%a, %d %b %Y, %h:%i:%s %p') AS local_time FROM `timezone` tz JOIN `zone` z ON tz.zone_id=z.zone_id WHERE tz.time_start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) AND z.zone_name='Asia/Manila'ORDER BY tz.time_start DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I want to be able to query the same day, date, and local_time by providing the latitude and longitude instead of the Timezone.

This will be for my university project. I'm using Java, Tomcat, Android, and MySQL if that helps. Thanks, Stack! and those who answers! :)

Comment: You'll have to solve a few different problems on that: DB of time zone borders and a query to get the data. I don't think this is possible to do with this DB...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! SO should not be used for homework.

Comment: I see. But, Timezonedb.com does return an xml containing values including the time by providing lat & long. This requires an API Key. I don't want to connect to the internet in my Android app, though. Thanks, Mr. Pastircak!

Comment: Really?? I think posting a question is good for the community, regardless of it's purpose. As long as it's a good question, though. And I could just say it's not for a university project.

**If SO doesn't allow this, I'll delete this.

Comment: You'll have to build your own database of latitudes and longitudes to time zone locations.  Don't forget to make it public and free once you've completed the database.

Comment: This blog entry may be useful: **[Mapping lat/lng's to timezones](https://sites.google.com/a/edval.biz/www/mapping-lat-lng-s-to-timezones)** It does provide code and data. And does not rely on a web service.

Comment: I was going to add that as an answer but, can't because of new user restrictions. Thanks for posting it as a comment, Mr. Vincent! :)